# Animate UIImageView start from rounded topRight corner and end with Rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am trying to animate my `ImageView`  which should appear from small Circle

Like this:
[image]

**Start Size**

`y = startFrame.origin.y + startFrame.size.height - 10`

```
height = 10 , width = 10
```

Top right round only

**EndFrame**

The original Rectangle

> ImageView Content should not shrink or expand , it's content should be
>   appear like the above Screenshot .

it is possible to do in iOS ?

Comment: Add the code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this solution right here, it works from iOS 11 and above

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {

        roundedView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        self.roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        }, completion: nil )

    }
```

here is also the reference:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/masked-and-animated-corners/